# How to solve the GLMakie Precompiling error in Julia?

Tags: julia, makie.jl

I was plotting my heatmap using Makie. It was working fine but suddenly I get this error trying to run the GLMakie package. CairoMakie worked fine.

```
using GLMakie 

[ Info:  [e9467ef8-e4e7-5192-8a1a-b1aee30e663a]  ERROR: LoadError: KeyError: key :colormap not found
Stacktrace:
  [1] getindex(h::Dict{Symbol, Observables.Observable}, key::Symbol)
    @ Base ./dict.jl:481
  [2] getindex
    @ ~/.julia/packages/MakieCore/8YGMv/src/attributes.jl:96 [inlined]
  [3] getindex(x::MakieCore.Mesh{Tuple{GeometryBasics.Mesh{2, Float32, GeometryBasics.Ngon{2, Float32, 3, GeometryBasics.Point{2, Float32}}, GeometryBasics.SimpleFaceView{2, Float32, 3, GeometryBasics.OffsetInteger{-1, UInt32}, GeometryBasics.Point{2, Float32}, GeometryBasics.NgonFace{3, GeometryBasics.OffsetInteger{-1, UInt32}}}}}}, key::Symbol)
    @ MakieCore ~/.julia/packages/MakieCore/8YGMv/src/attributes.jl:192

*<skipping abundant error messages>*

ERROR: Failed to precompile GLMakie [e9467ef8-e4e7-5192-8a1a-b1aee30e663a] to /home/mikheev/.julia/compiled/v1.7/GLMakie/jl_OWtvbO.
```

while my heatmap code gave me this error:

```
let

    ix = sortperm([a[1] for a in argmax(dat_e[28,:,:], dims=1)][1,:])                                                                           
    ix = ix[2000:6000]
    f, ax, hm = CairoMakie.heatmap((dat_e[28,:,ix]), colormap=Reverse("RdBu"), colorrange = (-40, 40))
   ax = current_axis()
    ax.xlabel = "Time [sec]"
    ax.ylabel = "Sorted trials"
    CairoMakie.Colorbar(f[:, end+1], hm, label = "Voltage [µV]") 
    hidespines!(ax, :t, :r) 
    f
end


MethodError: no method matching to_color(::MakieCore.Automatic)
Closest candidates are:
  to_color(!Matched::Number) at ~/.julia/packages/Makie/bwZTV/src/conversions.jl:763
  to_color(!Matched::Colorant) at ~/.julia/packages/Makie/bwZTV/src/conversions.jl:764
  to_color(!Matched::Makie.AbstractPattern) at ~/.julia/packages/Makie/bwZTV/src/conversions.jl:769
```

Any ideas how to solve it? Both problems occured simultaneously after I restarted my VSCode.

Comment: This just looks like a bug. https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Makie.jl/issues/2187 probably the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pkg.update() solved the problem.

The problem was in the outdated version of the GLMakie.

Comment: also I used WGLMakie - works the same, has no such problems

Answer (score 0):

If you get any error loading GLMakie, it likely means, you don't have an OpenGL capable Graphic Card, or you don't have an OpenGL 3.3 capable video driver installed. Note, that most GPUs, even 8 year old integrated ones, support OpenGL 3.3.

https://github.com/MakieOrg/Makie.jl/tree/master/GLMakie#troubleshooting-opengl